# How to give input streams in python?

Tags: python

i'm uninstall some packages in Linux via python os module my code like

```
def uninstallZdev():
    print 'Uninstallation as a Super User'
    system('apt-get remove xxx')

uninstallPackage()
```

but remove package ask like

**After this operation, 2,621 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?** 
how to give Y in program via python

Comment: how to automate the Y give to terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure `apt-get` not to ask (see the [`apt-get` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

```
apt-get --assume-yes remove xxx
```

For tools that cannot be configured, use [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to steer the process. `pexpect` lets you listen for output from a subprocess, and send input based on a simple API:

```
import pexpect

ag = pexpect.spawn('apt-get remove xxx')
ag.expect('Do you want to continue')
ag.send('Y')
ag.wait()
ag.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-y` to automate apt-get. Thus, you don't have to simulate the "y"-press.

Btw, I'd recommend using the subprocess-module, especially if you're planing to work with stdin/stdout.

And: be carefull! You seem to run this as root, or with sudo. If `xxx` happens to be libc-bin for some reason, you'll have fun restoring your system.